# External Javascript on click loading then using its API

Tags: javascript, tawk.to

So been looking for a good chat program that has a windows app. Found [Tawk](https://www.tawk.to/) I pretty large app so I wanted to load it only if someone really wanted to chat with me.

The problem is once you click my chat button, the chat box is in a minimized state. I would like the widget to maximize once its loaded. They have an [api](https://www.tawk.to/javascript-api/) to maximize.

```
Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
    Tawk_API.maximize();
};
```

Unfortunately, this only works when the program is fully loaded.

I tried a timer function that looks for a class but they change there class names on each load `class="KSKLwOL-1492537819846"`.

Hope there might be another approach to know when the program is loaded then maximize.

```
$('.chat').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.chat').hide();
    var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {},
        Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
    (function () {
        var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
            s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async = true;
        s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/58f11df330ab263079b5fde1/default';
        s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
        document.body.appendChild(s0);
    })();
});
```

The chat program is loaded on my [site](https://rgfx.net) if you want to see what I mean.

Thanks, anybody.

Comment: I think this could be done with promises or async-await. I might try to, because I agree this chat app is way too large.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to load API and `hide` widget as default using

```
Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
  Tawk_API.hideWidget();
};
```

and on your button click

```
$('.chat').on('click', function (e) {
$('.chat').hide();
Tawk_API.showWidget();
```

#### Update:

You are currently loading the `Tawk` api on your `chat button` click. I suggest you should load it on your page as `Tawk` recommended. Put your script before the `</body>` tag.

This will save you the hassle of timer or waiting for the API to load. In result, when you `DOM` is ready(fully loaded), you will have `Tawk` api object

#### HTML

```
<body>
    <! -- move your code given by Tawk here -->
</body>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (Tawk_API) {
     Tawk_API.onLoad = function() {
       Tawk_API.hideWidget();
     };
     $('.chat-button').on('click', function(){
       $('.chat-button').hide();
       Tawk_API.showWidget();
       Tawk_API.maximize();
     });
    }
 });
```

Still, if this is not understandable, Here is a codepen demonstration of what I meant to say . [Check this link](https://codepen.io/farooqkhan/pen/MmKWRO)

Comment: I tried that your solution first, it takes time for the widget to load so it doesn't work, Tawk_API is not defined. :( - I meant I would like it to maximize, edited my post.

Comment: I think we are not on same page. Let me edit my answer

Comment: I know how they want me to do, but that is not how it should be done. looking at things from Site Speed/SEO/UX perspective. I don't want to load a heavy chat widget that's bigger then my whole website that might not even be used. My Question is how to tell if the widget is loaded then call the function. Appreciate your time nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that the widget minimizes on load, note the setTimeout is important to achieve this. It's always good to stick with the tawk to API.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {};
  var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
    s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s1.async = true;
    s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/5b161b708859f57bdc7bd84d/default';
    s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
    s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
    s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);

//here's all you need
Tawk_API.onLoad = function() {
setTimeout(function() {
      Tawk_API.minimize();
    }, 1);
};
</script>
```